# Check if Address Book contact phone number is mobile

Tags: objective-c, abaddressbook

I can successfully retrieve the phone numbers associated to a contact, but for sharing purposes I need to find out which number is the contact's mobile phone number.

The type can be retrieved using the following code;

```
ABMultiValueRef phonesRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
 if(phonesRef) {
        long count = ABMultiValueGetCount(phonesRef);
        for(int ix = 0; ix < count; ix++){
            CFStringRef typeTmp = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phonesRef, ix);
            CFStringRef numberRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phonesRef, ix);
            CFStringRef typeRef = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(typeTmp);


            CFStringRef typeRef = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(typeTmp);
            NSString *phoneType = (__bridge NSString *)typeRef;
        }
}
```

However, how do I check if that very type is mobile? I mean sure, I could just compare the String to "mobile", but naturally that won't work in a localized environment.

Is there a constant I can compare this to?

Comment: How did you get `typeTmp`?

Comment: Sorry, edited the answer.

Comment: So you are looking at the label assigned by the user to the phone number. It can be anything, not just "mobile" (even ignoring other languages).

Comment: Ah crap, you're right, didn't remember that the label can be custom as well. Any other ways to select a mobile phone number from the stack of phone numbers?

Comment: No good ideas beyond looking for "mobile", "cell", "iPhone", etc. and various translations.

Comment: Hm... not a good solution I'm afraid. Unless iOS does some sort of magic trickery in the background to automatically select an appropriate phone number that I'm not aware of, I guess a dialog where the user has to select the phone number first.

Comment: In the UK, you can look at the phone number and see if it is mobile or not. Numbers starting with 07 are mobile.

Comment: @gnasher729, unfurtunately, such rules don't apply on an international scale. For instance, in germany there is no such rule of thumb.